# Thresholding an image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How to transform input gray scale image into a binary image, based on an optimal threshold value, which is the average of the maximum and minimum intensity of the image in matlab ?

Answer (score 4):

The way of doing that is quite easy:

```
th=mean([max(img(:)) min(img(:)]))  % mean of max-min gray values

BWimg=img>th;
```

Howere, just for your info, there are different "optimal threshold values", and the most common one in image processing is [OTSU's threshold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu's_method).

You can get that value in matlab by doing:

```
th=graythresh(img)
```

DOCS: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/graythresh.html

Comment: +1 You could replace the two `BWimg` lines by the simpler `BWimg = img>th;`

Comment: @LuisMendo Yeah, I knew, its just the op seems a bit confused about Matlab in general so I wanted to make it easy. But well, shorter==easier usually, so I edit my answer

Comment: Even `mean` is a bit of overkill.  I would simply add up the two values and divide by 2 as that is what the average would be.  Calling `mean` would incur additional overhead for error checking and all that, so I would just add and divide by 2.  Otherwise, good answer!

Comment: @rayryeng yup, my bad. The first version of the answer used the mean value of all the pixels, I though op wanted that. But sure, for the mean of 2 values no need of the function

Answer (score 0):

```
binary_img = gray_scale_img > mean([maximum_intensity,minimum_intensity]);
```